# Using BASH, how would one use "du -ch" to output only the total collective size?

Tags: du

I'm trying to run `du -ch` on multiple directories, but I only apart it only shows the total size of all files (I don't want each individual file, then the total at the end which is what `-c`does).

Comment: Can you not use `tail`?

Answer (score 4):

To resolve this issue, run the following command as parameter passing directories.

```
du -hs
```

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

```
$ du -sh .
$ du -chs *
$ du -chs * | tail -1
```